# Tag Links not linking to expected page

Tags: support, tags

I am experiencing an issue with this Exchange where clicking on the tag associated with a question, I am brought to a barren page.

For example, I've clicked the [league-of-legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/league-of-legends) tag and it returns zero results, while the tag itself claims to have over 1,000 questions tag'd as such.

I've not experienced this on any other Exchange, so I am curious to know what is happening here.

Comment: No repro here -- even your link shows all the expected questions.

Comment: Do you have the tag on ignore?

Comment: @FAE Ignore does not hide the questions on the tag's filter.

Comment: That said, do you happen to be on the "featured" tab?

Comment: Might also have it set to default to the Unanswered tab; the choice of tab on that screen is sticky, and if you view a tag while nothing's unanswered, you get an empty list.

Comment: @BillyMailman Unanswered has quite a bunch of questions for LoL ;)

Comment: @FEichinger Ah, or featured, yeah. It's not an option on the page, but you can still manually set it to featured with the URL, and it sticks, same as any other choice.

Comment: @FEichinger None older than August, though, so it may well have been empty before.

Comment: Configuration for this Exchange has been changed such that the default page when clicking a tag takes you to questions about the tag.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're probably on the "featured" tab, which filters by *questions with an active bounty*.

[image: Screenshot]

Click on any of the other tabs (top right in the screenshot) for other filters and information about the tag.

Comment: also the default is 'newest' IIRC

Comment: Yes, but the point is that this *was* the only exchange that acted this way by default.

Comment: @earthmeLon It doesn't act like this by default. You opened the featured tab at one point and from then on it will always display the featured tab until you switch again. That's the same behaviour as any other SE site.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the explanation.  Like I said, I've never experienced this before so I felt as though it was strange behavior.